# Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json' after installing Windows Phone 8 SDK

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, windows-phone-8-sdk

Projects that were working fine before installing the *Phone SDK* are now raising the following error at runtime:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral
>       , PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot 
>       find the file specified.

Exception details:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json
>        , Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of 
>        its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The following line entries are from the `Global.asax.cs` file.

```
Line 17: AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
Line 18: 
Line 19: WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
Line 20: FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
Line 21: RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was resolved by re installing the Json.NET NuGet package.

I couldn't uninstall it because of other package dependencies, but the Online tab of NuGet didn't think the package was installed, so didn't object to re installing again.